# Change multi select plugin placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I am using http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/ for a multi-select,filter select box.  Everything works fine, but one thing I feel difficult is I have different select boxes and for each select box I need different placeholder.  Currently I am initiating like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".multi-select-filter").multipleSelect({
        filter:true,
        width:"100%",
        placeholder : "Select Zone(s)"
    });
</script>
```

This is something repeating in all the pages.  Is there any way, I can make this call in a common js file and change or override the place holder value only in individual pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute on each element to place the required placeholder message like `<select class="multi-select-filter" placeholder="some message"></select>` then in your common file

```
$(".multi-select-filter").each(function () {
    $(this).multipleSelect({
        filter: true,
        width: "100%",
        placeholder: $(this).attr('placeholder')
    });
})
```